# Why is the electrode with the lower reduction potential the cathode?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

Wouldn't it make sense that the electrode with the higher reduction potential be the cathode, since reduction occurs at the cathode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you misunderstand the meaning of reduction potential. Reduction potential refers to the voltage required to reduce a material under standard conditions. If a material has a higher reduction potential it takes more energy to reduce it than a lower reduction potential material. Therefore the higher reduction potential material is actually oxidized to reduce the lower reduction potential material.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with a higher (more positive) reduction potential than some other molecule will have a tendency to gain electrons from this molecule (i.e. to be reduced by oxidizing this other molecule) and a solution with a lower (more negative) reduction potential will have a tendency to lose electrons to other substances.

Comment: This response does not add substantially to the previous ones.

Comment: Don't you notice that the previous answer is wrong? The answer is YES.

Comment: The reduction potential of copper is 0.52V and the reduction potential of Zinc is -0.76V. Copper is the Cathode and Zinc is Anode in a Cu-Zn Sulfuric Acid battery.